# (VB.Net) Is there a way for one method to access another method's variables?

Tags: vb.net

If I define an array in the scope of a method, is it possible for another method to have access to it? I would make it global, but I only know the bounds of the array at the end of the first method.

Comment: You don't have to create the array at the same time you declare it so you could make it global. Equally you could use `ReDim` to change the bounds after you create it. However, I doubt either of these is the best solution for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, that was the easiest way for me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only other option is you pass it as a parameter to your 'other method' if you dont want to make it global.

Otherwise I would suggest capturing both the array and its bounds in a class and save that as a global (instance variable) so you know both the array and its bounds when used in another method. You can check to make sure the bounds and the array are valid before attempting to use it to avoid run time errors.